# How can I show the results after Bash reads one complete line of input but before executing any of the commands on that line?

Tags: bash, command-line, alias

From the [Bash manual, Section 6.6 Aliases](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Aliases),

> … 
>    Bash always **reads** at least one complete line of input before
>   **executing** any of the commands on that line. 
>   Aliases are expanded when a command is **read**, not when it is
>   **executed**. Therefore, an alias definition appearing on the same line as another command does not take effect until the next line of
>   input is read.

Here I am trying to find a way to understand      [Which of the following operations does shell perform when "reading a complete line of input" and when "executing any of the commands in the line"?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/383796/which-of-the-following-operations-does-shell-perform-when-reading-a-complete-li)

Are there some commands and examples which can show the results

- **after**  Bash   **reads**   one complete line of input
- but **before** **executing** any of the commands on that line ?

For example,

- "one complete line of input" is a compound command which consists of several commands.
- "one complete line of input" can also be a pipeline of several compound commands, a list of pipelines, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The part of the Bash manual you quoted talks about

> Aliases are expanded when a command is read, not when it is executed. Therefore, an alias definition appearing on the same line as another command does not take effect until the next line of input is read.

So aliases are actually one of those examples that show the difference between reading and executing a line!

To clarify, here is a compound command. We first try to define an alias, and then we try to use it:

`alias echo=uname; echo`

Someone who is unfamiliar with Bash would expect that the output of that command is `Linux` (or whatever OS you're running), but it actually it just outputs nothing. This is because Bash first **reads** the line and applies alias definitions. So this is what Bash sees:

`alias echo=uname; echo`

Note that the second `echo` is not converted to `uname`. This is because Bash hasn't executed our `alias echo=uname` command yet, it has only *read* it. After Bash has read the line, it executes what it has read. Therefore it executes:

`alias echo=uname; echo` (which is exactly what it read, as described above)

We can even check that Bash executed the command by typing `echo`. Since we have defined an alias before, `echo` will now be converted to `uname` during the read step, so Bash will execute `uname`.

#### In short:

```
$ alias echo=uname; echo

$ echo
Linux
```

#### Edit:

After your edit, you asked whether there is a way to show the results after Bash reads one line of input, but before actually executing them. The answer is yes, but it's not very convenient for every-day use (however, it's certainly useful for understanding what's going on inside the shell).

Create a file with the following contents:

```
#!/bin/bash
shopt -s expand_aliases
trapped() {
    echo "On line ${1}, Bash sees: $BASH_COMMAND"
}
trap 'trapped ${LINENO}' DEBUG
alias echo=uname; echo
echo
```

Then, execute that file.

Here is an explanation of how that script is working:

- `shopt -s expand_aliases` tells Bash to expand aliases even when it is in noninteractive mode (such as in this case)
- We then define a function `trapped()`. When called, this function will print the command that is currently executed (along with a line number, that gets passed as parameter).
- We call `trap 'trapped ${LINENO}' DEBUG`. This tells Bash "whenever you see a signal called `DEBUG`, execute `trapped ${LINENO}` first. `DEBUG` is a signal that is automatically generated by Bash **before any execution of a simple command**. In other words, before any command is executed, our function `trapped()` is called.
- Lastly, we execute a few commands for demonstration. However, since we have a trap going, `trapped()` is executed before anything else happens, so Bash prints what is about to be executed. The `LINENO` variable is just a Bash built-in, that gives us the current linenumber.

If you want to be able to "run" commands without executing them at all and still see what Bash reads, you might want to look into the `extdebug` option in the Bash manual.

Comment: Thanks. Is it possible to show the results **after**  Bash reads   one complete line of input **but before** executing  any of the commands on that line? Sorry that I didn't make my question clear.

Comment: @Tim I added an explanation to my answer. That was harder than I thought it would be. Today I learned :)

Comment: Thanks again.    
Here I am trying to find away to understand       https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/383796/which-of-the-following-operations-does-shell-perform-when-reading-a-complete-li

Comment: Regarding "If you want to be able to 'run' commands without executing them at all and still see what Bash reads, you might want to look into the extdebug option in the Bash manual", after I run `shopt -s extdebug`, I don't see any information displayed when I run a command in bash. Am I missing something?

Comment: @Tim Ah, sorry, I didn't make this clear enough. You're doing the right thing. What I meant was that `extdebug` can be used to surpress execution of commands. The description of `extdebug` says `If the command run by the DEBUG trap returns a non-zero value, the next command is skipped and not executed`. So you can use `trap` and the `extdebug` option in combination to skip the execution of commands. Additionally, traps themselves can be used to print information about the commands, like I did in my answer.

Comment: Thanks again. What can "skip the execution of commands" be used for? Is it used for some debugging purpose?

Comment: @Tim Exactly. Say for example, you have some command that contains some aliases, but you don't want to let it execute because it could potentially be dangerous. You could use `trap` and `extdebug` together and skip the execution of that command, but still print what was about to be executed.

Answer (score 3):

A good way to understand this would be to take a look at this example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38526612/bash-unable-to-set-and-use-alias-in-the-same-line

For example, you want to execute the following command:

```
$ alias foo="echo bac" ; foo;
-bash: foo: command not found
$ foo
bac
```

Now bash will read the whole line and since `foo` is not aliased yet it will not expand (aliases are expanded while reading). Now while executing the line it'll set the alias and throw an error.

Comment: Thanks. Is it possible to show the results **after**  Bash reads   one complete line of input **but before** executing  any of the commands on that line? Sorry that I didn't make my question clear.

Answer (score 2):

Your question isn’t crystal clear, but your juxtaposition of the sentences

> Aliases are expanded when a command is **read**,
>   not when it is **executed**.

and

> Bash always **reads** at least one complete line of input before
>   **executing** any of the commands on that line.

suggests that the focus of your question is alias expansion. 
(I say “suggests” because, aside from the Bash manual excerpt,
your question doesn't mention aliases at all.)

The original version of your question asked

> How can I show that Bash always reads at least one complete line of input before executing any of the commands on that line?

The only real way to do this
is to use some sort of debugging / monitoring / trace tool
to examine the shell’s internal state. 
That’s somewhat impractical. 
[PawkyPenguin’s answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/383802/80216#383806) shows an approach
to making a hand-wavy argument to support what the manual says. 
Here’s a variation of their answer that (IMO) is a little clearer:

```
$ alias myalias=date

$ alias myalias="ls -ld"; myalias
Fri, Aug 04, 2017  3:33:33 AM
```

We can argue that
the shell must have read the (second) complete line in its entirety
before it started to execute it 
because, when it executed `myalias`, it executed it as `date`. 
By the time the `myalias` alias was executed,
it had been redefined to be `ls -ld`. 
Therefore, the shell must have expanded `myalias` to `date`
before it executed the

```
alias myalias="ls -ld"
```

command, so it must have read the complete line of input
before executing any of the commands on that line.

---

Your revised question,

> How can I show the results after Bash reads one complete line of input but before executing any of the commands on that line?

makes a little more sense in this context. 
I guess you want to see the command line *with aliases expanded* 
before executing any of the commands on that line;
i.e., see the results of alias expansion. 
I guess you want to see something like

```
alias myalias="ls -ld"; date
```

As far as I know, there isn’t any way to get that output
— the complete line with aliases expanded. 
But the `xtrace` (`-x`) option comes close.

```
$ set -x

$ alias myalias=date
+ alias myalias=date

$ alias myalias="ls -ld"; myalias
+ alias 'myalias=ls -ld'
+ date                                                         ← The expansion of the alias
Fri, Aug 04, 2017  3:33:42 AM
```

Of course, this outputs each expanded command
only just before it is executed, so the results of alias expansion
are intermixed with the output from the commands. 
Also, this shows *all* expansions:

```
$ animal=cat
+ animal=cat

$ echo Hello; echo world; myalias "$animal" R*
+ echo Hello
Hello
+ echo world
world
+ ls -ld cat README                                            ← The expansion of the alias
ls: cannot access cat: No such file or directory
-rw-r--r-- 2 myusername  mygroupname  489 Feb 22  2015 README
```

We don’t get to see `ls -ld "$animal" R*`;
we see it only after variable expansion and pathname (glob) expansion. 
Neither does it “play well” with pipelines:

```
$ alias myalias=date
+ alias myalias=date

$ myalias | od -cb
+ date                                                         ← The expansion of the alias
+ od -cb
0000000   F   r   i   ,       A   u   g       0   4   ,       2   0   1
        106 162 151 054 040 101 165 147 040 060 064 054 040 062 060 061
0000020   7           9   :   4   2   :   1   7       P   M  \n
        067 040 040 071 072 064 062 072 061 067 040 120 115 012
0000036
```

where the trace output shows us `date` and `od -cb` on two separate lines. 
(You would need to look at the original command line
to figure out that it was doing `date | od -cb`,
if it wasn’t obvious from the output.)

Comment: Thanks.sorry for not being clear at first. Here I am trying to find a way to understand      https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/383796/which-of-the-following-operations-does-shell-perform-when-reading-a-complete-li